# I must disconnect and connect again everytime to use wifi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, internet

I use Ubuntu 16.04. I must disconnect and connect again to wifi network if I want to work with the internet! My internet only works for 30seconds after connecting again!

This is the Ubuntu's problem, cause the network is OK as there are many other connected devices work well.

Also, it's interesting that to say, when I use VPN services, after VPN connected, it seems my internet works well, but when I disconnect the VPN, I should disconnect and connect again for every 30 seconds if I want my internet works!!